# javascript calculation grand total result become double

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a simple accounting calculator.

Maybe the word calculator would be more vast according to my project nature. In fact it is simple transaction calculation.

First fall it deals with

> item rate
>
> item qnt
>
> total amnt of each item (rate*qnt)

I did it, now all row `amnt` should be sum and set result as **Grand total** with condition - the requirement. Indeed, I can't handle this condition.

condition can be

> discount
>
> tax

to the **sum** of **total items** user can apply **discount(+)**, **tax(%)**, **loss(-)** whatever he wish, I am able to get result of these conditions also, but while merging result or to get grand total, it becomes mess and output in grand total comes randomly.

For example, user bought

```
item    qnt     rate    amnt
pen     1200    2       2400
copy    200     20      4000

Now
13% vat included    + (//user can enter with % sigh, amount would be 492)
200 Discount got    - 200

Grand total should be 6692
```

My result is **8172.16** almost double. I prefer pure JavaScript, if it is becomes more easier with Jquery is also good.

```js
window.onload=function(){
  itm_qnt_rte();
  dsc_vat();
}

  function itm_qnt_rte(){
      var rte = document.querySelectorAll('.rte');
      for(var i=0;i<rte.length;i++){
          rte[i].onchange=function(){
              var rate = parseInt(this.value);
              var qnt = parseInt(this.closest('tr').querySelector('.qnt').value);
              if(rate > 0 && qnt >0){
                  var amnt = rate*qnt;
                  this.closest('tr').querySelector('.amnt').value = amnt;
                  var sum = 0;
                  var g_ttl = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.amnt');
                  for(k=0;k<g_ttl.length;k++){
                      var value = parseInt(g_ttl[k].value);
                      if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                          sum += parseFloat(value);
                      }
                  this.closest('table').querySelector('.g_ttl').value = sum;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      var qnt = document.querySelectorAll('.qnt');
      for(var i=0;i<qnt.length;i++){
          qnt[i].onchange=function(){
              var qnt = parseInt(this.value);
              var rte = parseInt(this.closest('tr').querySelector('.rte').value);
              if(rte > 0 && qnt >0){
                  var amnt = rte*qnt;
                  this.closest('tr').querySelector('.amnt').value = amnt;
                  var sum = 0;
                  var g_ttl = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.amnt');
                  for(k=0;k<g_ttl.length;k++){
                      var value = parseInt(g_ttl[k].value);
                      if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                          sum += parseFloat(value);
                      }
                  this.closest('table').querySelector('.g_ttl').value = sum;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  
  function dsc_vat(){
    var dsc_vat = document.querySelectorAll('.dv');
    for(var a=0;a<dsc_vat.length;a++){
        dsc_vat[a].onchange = function(){
        var sum = 0;
        var g_ttl = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.amnt');
        for(k=0;k<g_ttl.length;k++){
            var value = parseInt(g_ttl[k].value);
            if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(value);
            }
        }
        var selected = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.dv');
        for(var b=0;b<selected.length;b++){
          var value = this.value;
          var gttl = 0;
          if (value !== '') {
            if (value[value.length - 1] === '%') {
              gttl = ((sum * parseInt(value)) / 100);
            }
            if (value[value.length - 1] !== '%') {
              gttl = parseInt(value);
            }
            var n = gttl * 1;
            if (n >= 0) {
            sum = sum + gttl
            } else {
            sum = sum - Math.abs(gttl);
            }
          }
          if (value == '' || value === '0') {
            this.value=0;
          }
          this.closest('tr').querySelector('.dv_amnt').value = gttl;
        }
         this.closest('table').querySelector('.g_ttl').value = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.txtcenter{
  text-align:center
}
.txtright{
  text-align:right
}
.g_ttl{
  border:2px solid red;
}
table{
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Particulars</th><th>Qnt</th><th>Rate</th><th>amnt</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pen</td><td><input type='text' class='qnt'></td><td><input type='text' class='rte' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='amnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pencil</td><td><input type='text' class='qnt'></td><td><input type='text' class='rte' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='amnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='txtcenter'>Discount</td><td><input type='text' class='dv' /></td><td><input type='text' class='dv_amnt' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='txtcenter'>Tax</td><td><input type='text' class='dv' /></td><td><input type='text' class='dv_amnt' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan='3'>Grand Total</td><td><input type='text' class='g_ttl' /></td></tr>
      
    </table>

Table 2
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Particulars</th><th>Qnt</th><th>Rate</th><th>amnt</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pen</td><td><input type='text' class='qnt'></td><td><input type='text' class='rte' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='amnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pencil</td><td><input type='text' class='qnt'></td><td><input type='text' class='rte' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='amnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='txtcenter'>Discount</td><td><input type='text' class='dv' /></td><td><input type='text' class='dv_amnt' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='txtcenter'>Tax</td><td><input type='text' class='dv' /></td><td><input type='text' class='dv_amnt' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan='3'>Grand Total</td><td><input type='text' class='g_ttl' /></td></tr>
      
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes my explanation.
There are a few logic flaws which we have to take care of first.

1) You are using the same function to calculate discount and tax. And discount needs to be subtracted from the sum not added. Hece, I multiplied the discount value by -1.

2) The reason you were getting the sum as almost double is because you used the class dv for both discount and tax due to which the length was calculated as 2 instead of 1.

3) I have added a routine to calculate the tax separately and used a class '**dv_tax**' specifically for tax calculation

I have made an assumption that the tax calculation is done after the discount is applied.
**Note: In case of your program, the user needs to input all values in sequential order to calculate the discount and tax correctly i.e after adding discount or tax, if the user decides to change the input rate or qty he has to delete the tax and discount rates and key it in again. You can use additional onChange functions to recalculate tax and discount when any of the value changes.**

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Particulars</th><th>Qnt</th><th>Rate</th><th>amnt</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pen</td><td><input type='text' class='qnt'></td><td><input type='text' class='rte' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='amnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pencil</td><td><input type='text' class='qnt'></td><td><input type='text' class='rte' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='amnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='txtcenter'>Discount</td><td><input type='text' class='dv' /></td><td><input type='text' class='dv_amnt total_discount' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='txtcenter'>Tax</td><td><input type='text' class='dv_tax' /></td><td><input type='text' class='dv_amnt' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan='3'>Grand Total</td><td><input type='text' class='g_ttl' /></td></tr>

    </table>

Table 2
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Particulars</th><th>Qnt</th><th>Rate</th><th>amnt</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pen</td><td><input type='text' class='qnt'></td><td><input type='text' class='rte' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='amnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pencil</td><td><input type='text' class='qnt'></td><td><input type='text' class='rte' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='amnt'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='txtcenter'>Discount</td><td><input type='text' class='dv' /></td><td><input type='text' class='dv_amnt total_discount' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='txtcenter'>Tax</td><td><input type='text' class='dv_tax' /></td><td><input type='text' class='dv_amnt' /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td colspan='3'>Grand Total</td><td><input type='text' class='g_ttl' /></td></tr>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload=function(){
itm_qnt_rte();
dsc_vat();
tax_vat();
}

function itm_qnt_rte(){
    var rte = document.querySelectorAll('.rte');
    for(var i=0;i<rte.length;i++){
        rte[i].onchange=function(){
            var rate = parseInt(this.value);
            var qnt = parseInt(this.closest('tr').querySelector('.qnt').value);
            if(rate > 0 && qnt >0){
                var amnt = rate*qnt;
                this.closest('tr').querySelector('.amnt').value = amnt;
                var sum = 0;
                var g_ttl = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.amnt');
                for(k=0;k<g_ttl.length;k++){
                    var value = parseInt(g_ttl[k].value);
                    if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                        sum += parseFloat(value);
                    }
                this.closest('table').querySelector('.g_ttl').value = sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var qnt = document.querySelectorAll('.qnt');
    for(var i=0;i<qnt.length;i++){
        qnt[i].onchange=function(){
            var qnt = parseInt(this.value);
            var rte = parseInt(this.closest('tr').querySelector('.rte').value);
            if(rte > 0 && qnt >0){
                var amnt = rte*qnt;
                this.closest('tr').querySelector('.amnt').value = amnt;
                var sum = 0;
                var g_ttl = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.amnt');
                for(k=0;k<g_ttl.length;k++){
                    var value = parseInt(g_ttl[k].value);
                    if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                        sum += parseFloat(value);
                    }
                this.closest('table').querySelector('.g_ttl').value = sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function dsc_vat(){
  var dsc_vat = document.querySelectorAll('.dv');
  for(var a=0;a<dsc_vat.length;a++){
      dsc_vat[a].onchange = function(){
      var sum = 0;
      var g_ttl = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.amnt');
      for(k=0;k<g_ttl.length;k++){
          var value = parseInt(g_ttl[k].value);
          if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
              sum += parseFloat(value);
          }
      }

      var selected = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.dv');
      for(var b=0;b<selected.length;b++){
        var value = this.value;
        var gttl = 0;
        if (value !== '') {
          if (value[value.length - 1] === '%') {
            gttl = ((sum * parseInt(value)) / 100);
            gttl = gttl*-1;
          }
          if (value[value.length - 1] !== '%') {
            gttl = parseInt(value);
            gttl = gttl*-1;
          }
          var n = gttl * 1;
          if (n >= 0) {
          sum = sum + gttl
          } else {
          sum = sum - Math.abs(gttl);
          }
        }
        if (value == '' || value === '0') {
          this.value=0;
        }
        this.closest('tr').querySelector('.dv_amnt').value = Math.abs(gttl);
      }
       this.closest('table').querySelector('.g_ttl').value = sum;
      }
  }
}

function tax_vat(){
  var tax_vat = document.querySelectorAll('.dv_tax');
  for(var a=0;a<tax_vat.length;a++){
      tax_vat[a].onchange = function(){
      var sum = 0;
      var g_ttl = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.amnt');
      for(k=0;k<g_ttl.length;k++){
          var value = parseInt(g_ttl[k].value);
          if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
              sum += parseFloat(value);
          }
      }

      var disc_select = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.total_discount');
      sum = sum - disc_select[0].value;

      var selected = this.closest('table').querySelectorAll('.dv_tax');
      for(var b=0;b<selected.length;b++){
        var value = this.value;
        var gttl = 0;
        if (value !== '') {
          if (value[value.length - 1] === '%') {
            gttl = ((sum * parseInt(value)) / 100);
          }
          if (value[value.length - 1] !== '%') {
            gttl = parseInt(value);
          }
          var n = gttl * 1;
          if (n >= 0) {
          sum = sum + gttl
          } else {
          sum = sum - Math.abs(gttl);
          }
        }
        if (value == '' || value === '0') {
          this.value=0;
        }
        this.closest('tr').querySelector('.dv_amnt').value = Math.abs(gttl);
      }
       this.closest('table').querySelector('.g_ttl').value = sum;
      }
  }
}
```